# Get a Event from asp.net's validators to jquery on status change

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation

i would like to have an event fired in jquery, if the validators of my page change their states.

This is my usecase:

1. In an Adressform the Validators all are hidden.
2. If i submit the form, the get displayed.
3. Now i want to fire a jQuery function, which renders all rows (not the inputfields, but their parents) with a red border (means add a css class)
4. if i now change the field and the validator hides i also want to hide the border around the input's parent

i don't want to have a timer checking every 100ms the displayed validators (which would work perfectly), but i want to listen only to the show/hide events of the validators

any ideas, how i can add a listener to the change events of a validator?

regards
Christoph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can call .NET validators from JavaScript:
[Manually calling ASP.NET Validation with JavaScript](http://blog.devlpr.net/2008/09/19/manually-calling-aspnet-validation-with-javascript/)
You could integrate the above with jQuery events or [jQuery Validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation).

NOTE: This solution is if you are tied to .NET Validators, otherwise just use jQuery Validation as Dave mentioned.

Comment: as i wanted to keep the asp.net validation working i used the method from your Link (add a functzion to the buttons click event, call the Page_ClientValidate ans check the validators on the page)
Thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the standard [jQuery validator plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)?  I'm pretty sure its validators have events you can hook into in just the way you describe.

Comment: I wanted a event from the asp.net validators to jquery, not the other direction.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering this old question, but I made a blog post about [modifying the default javacscript evaluation function of the ASP.NET validators](http://tseonet.blogspot.be/2013/03/override-default-aspnet-validator.html). Basically it comes down to this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < window.Page_Validators.length; i++) {
    // Create a new property and assign the original evaluation function to it
    window.Page_Validators[i].baseEvaluationFunction = window.Page_Validators[i].evaluationfunction;

    // Set our own validation function
    window.Page_Validators[i].evaluationfunction = evaluateField;
}
```

Next, in the 'evaluateField' function, write the code to set the css.

```
function evaluateField (validator) {
    // Run the original validation function
    var isvalid = validator.baseEvaluationFunction(validator);

    // Handle the result
    if (isvalid) {
        clearError(validator);
    } else {
        setError(validator);
    }

    // Return result
    return isvalid;
}
```

In the setError and clearError functions you can use jquery to find the parent row and apply css to it. Hope this helps!